# Django celery: class-based task doesn't work

Tags: django, django-celery

**tasks.py**

```
from celery import Task


class SimpleTask(Task):

    def run(self):
        print("run")
```

Execute `python manage.py shell`

```
In [3]: from products.tasks import SimpleTask

In [4]: task = SimpleTask()

In [6]: task.run()
run
```

Successfully work and no error logs come out in worker server.

Howerver,

```
In [7]: task.delay()
Out[7]: <AsyncResult: a2e90b17-2af9-49b4-82df-562955beaf69>
```

And worker server log shows errors:

```
[2016-11-05 18:44:03,171: ERROR/MainProcess] Received unregistered task of type None.
The message has been ignored and discarded.

Did you remember to import the module containing this task?
Or maybe you're using relative imports?

Please see
http://docs.celeryq.org/en/latest/internals/protocol.html
for more information.

The full contents of the message body was:
b'[[], {}, {"callbacks": null, "chord": null, "errbacks": null, "chain": null}]' (77b)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Chois/.pyenv/versions/3.5.1/envs/spacegraphy/lib/python3.5/site-packages/celery/worker/consumer/consumer.py", line 549, in on_task_received
    strategy = strategies[type_]
KeyError
```

I don't see why this happens. If I created function-based task using `@shared_task` it successfully works. But only class-based `Task` doesn't work.

Need helps, Thanks.

Comment: Solved: It doesn't work at 4.0.0. It works 3.1.25.

Comment: http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/whatsnew-4.0.html#the-task-base-class-no-longer-automatically-register-tasks

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with class based tasks, but not in Django. Fixed it by setting `name` attribute on the task.

```
class AddTask(celery.Task):
     name = 'AddTask'
```

Comment: This works for me in Django 3.2 + celery 5.2. Used the following to automatically set fully qualified name and register with the app: 
`from celery import Task; from myapp.celery import app; class AddTask(Task): pass; AddTask.name=f'{AddTask.__module__}.{AddTask.__qualname__}'; app.register_task(AddTask)`